# Text-align problems

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm playing around with html and css and have a question about the text-align functions.

I'm trying to build my own website and want the text-align set to start, but centred in the middle of the page. I've got it so that the content is centred, but when only text-align is set to centre. Is there a way to obtain centred text content but with text-align set to start? I don't particularly want to use padding (if it can be helped), as i've used it within this context and have had some responsive problems (which have had to be rectified with many media screen commands).

Sorry for the pretty noobie question.

HTML

```css
.Container1 {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: #e8eaed;
  background-size: cover;
  display: table;
  margin: auto;
  display: table;
  top: 0;
}

.About {
  font-family: 'Lato';
  font-weight: 300;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  max-width: none;
}

.Content2 {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.About h2 {
  font-size: 40px;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  line-height: 10px;
  font-style: italic;
  color: #70a1af;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px white;
  text-align: center;
}

.About p {
  font-size: 18px;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: #70a1af;
}
```

```html
<section class="Container1">
  <div class="About">
    <div class="Content2">
      <h2> ABOUT ME.</h2>
      <p> Computer Science // British Born // Wannabe Australian </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

[image]

This is how i want the text to be aligned, but to be centred in the middle of the page...

[image]

Comment: share your html...

Comment: @Bhuwan There you go mate

Comment: currently your text is centered...so what do you exactly want..?

Comment: @Bhuwan I've added an image of how i want the text to be aligned, but i want to be situated in the centre of the page, not the text alignment to be centred

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use [**Flexbox**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex). Use `align-item:center` to center flex item vertically.

***Stack Snippet***

```css
.Container1 {
  height: 400px;
  background: #e8eaed;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.About {
  font-family: 'Lato';
  font-weight: 300;
}

.About h2 {
  font-size: 40px;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  line-height: 10px;
  font-style: italic;
  color: #70a1af;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px white;
}

.About p {
  font-size: 18px;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: #70a1af;
}
```

```html
<section class="Container1">
  <div class="About">
    <div class="Content2">
      <h2> ABOUT ME.</h2>
      <p> Computer Science // British Born // Wannabe Australian </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

fixed the width and then set `margin: 0 auto`